# How to disable or hide carousel next/prev icons using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im using bootstrap4 carousel and i using carousel inside table.. i just create table pagination using carousel next/prev icon. now i struggle to create hide previous icon when we are in first page in carousel and show only next icon, then when we go to second page the prev icon wants to show.

same as well when we go last page the next icon wants to hide and show only prev icon.

any new approaches or suggestions please tell me..

here is my tried code..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myCarousel").carousel({
    interval: false
  });
});

pageSize = 3
incremSlide = 4
startPage = 0;
numberPage = 0;

var pageCount = $(".line-content").length / pageSize;
var totalSlidepPage = Math.floor(pageCount / incremSlide);

for (var i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
  $("#pagin").append('<li><a href="#">' + (i + 1) + '</a></li> ');
  if (i > pageSize) {
    $("#pagin li").eq(i).hide();
  }
}

var prev = $("<li/>").addClass("<").html(">").click(function() {
  startPage -= 3
  incremSlide -= 3
  slide();
});

prev.hide();

var next = $("<li/>").addClass("<").html(">").click(function() {
  startPage += 3;
  incremSlide += 3;
  slide();
});

$("#pagin").prepend(prev).append(next);

$("#pagin li").first().find("a").addClass("current");

slide = function(sens) {
  $("#pagin li").hide();

  for (t = startPage; t < incremSlide; t++) {
    $("#pagin li").eq(t + 1).show();
  }
  if (startPage == 0) {
    next.show();
    prev.hide();
  } else if (numberPage == totalSlidepPage) {
    next.hide();
    prev.show();
  } else {
    next.show();
    prev.show();
  }
}

showPage = function(page) {
  $(".line-content").hide();
  $(".line-content").each(function(n) {
    if (n >= pageSize * (page - 1) && n < pageSize * page)
      $(this).show();
  });
}

showPage(1);
$("#pagin li a").eq(0).addClass("current");

$("#pagin li a").click(function() {
  $("#pagin li a").removeClass("current");
  $(this).addClass("current");
  showPage(parseInt($(this).text()));
});
$('.carousel-control-prev').click(function(e) {
  var currentPage = parseInt($("#pagin li a.current").text());
  var prevPage = currentPage - 1;
  if (prevPage < pageSize) {
    showPage(prevPage);
    var currentObj = $("#pagin li a.current");
    $("#pagin li a.current").parent().prev().find('a').addClass('current');
    currentObj[0].className = "";

  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
$('.carousel-control-next').click(function(e) {
  var currentPage = parseInt($("#pagin li a.current").text());
  var nextPage = currentPage + 1;
  if (nextPage < pageSize) {
    showPage(nextPage);
    $("#pagin li a.current").parent().next().find('a').addClass('current');
    var currentObj = $("#pagin li a.current");
    currentObj[0].className = "";
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});

// tried another way

function carouselPage() {
  var checkitem = function() {
    var $this;
    $this = $("#myCarousel");
    if ($("#myCarousel .carousel-inner .item:first").hasClass("active")) {
      $this.children(".left").hide();
      $this.children(".right").show();
    } else if ($("#myCarousel .carousel-inner .item:last").hasClass("active")) {
      $this.children(".right").hide();
      $this.children(".left").show();
    } else {
      $this.children(".carousel-control").show();
    }
  };

  checkitem();

  $("#myCarousel").on("slid.bs.carousel", "", checkitem);
};
```

```css
#preModal .viewing {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  /* left: 23px; */
  width: 15px;
}

.carousel-control-prev {
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  top: 40%;
  left: 10px;
}

.carousel-control-next {
  right: 10px;
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  top: 40%;
}

.contd {
  /* width: 160%;
            right: 30%; */
  width: 132%;
  right: 16%;
}

.predefineModal {
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.current,
.carousel_li,
.carousel_a {
  display: none;
}


/* .contd:hover .carousel-control-next-icon {
        display: block;
    }
    
    .contd:hover .carousel-control-prev-icon {
        display: block;
    } */

.second {
  position: relative;
  right: 6%;
}

.modal-footer {
  max-width: 86%;
}

.indexBtn {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #680f79;
  border-color: #680f79;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 3px .75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: .25rem;
}

.indexBtn:hover {
  background-color: #c178cf;
}

.diss {
  color: #5f5e5e;
  background-color: #cecece;
  border-color: #cecece;
}

.btn {
  padding: 3px .75rem !important;
}

.periodTime {
  padding: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.carousel {
  /* background: #2f4357; */
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23680f79' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important;
  position: relative;
  right: 37px;
}

.carousel-control-next-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23680f79' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 4-4-4-4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important;
  position: relative;
  left: 37px;
}

ul#pagin {
  display: none;
}


/* .carousel-control-next,
    .carousel-control-prev {
        filter: invert(100%);
    } */


/* .carousel-control-prev-icon,
    .carousel-control-next-icon {
        position: relative;
        right: 2%;
        height: fit-content;
        width: fit-content;
        outline: black;
        background-size: 100%, 100%;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 1px solid black;
        background-image: none;
    }
    
    .carousel-control-next-icon:after {
        content: '>';
        font-size: 35px;
        color: #680f79;
        font-weight: 800;
    }
    
    .carousel-control-prev-icon:after {
        content: '<';
        font-size: 35px;
        color: #680f79;
        font-weight: 800;
    } */

.carousel-item {
  min-height: 180px;
  filter: blur(.0px) !important;
  /* transform: translateZ(0) !important; */
  backface-visibility: hidden !important;
  /* Prevent carousel from being distorted if for some reason image doesn't load */
}

.bs-example {
  margin: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  background-color: #9C27B0 !important;
}

.ui-widget.ui-widget-content {
  right: 0px !important;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 17px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>



<div class="modal-body predefineModal">
  <div class="bs-example">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
      <!-- Wrapper for carousel items -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
              <thead class="party_head">
                <tr>
                  <th>#</th>
                  <th>S.No</th>
                  <th>Trans.Type</th>
                  <th>Voucher Date</th>
                  <th>To A/c Name</th>
                  <th>Narration</th>
                  <th>Debit</th>
                  <th>Credit</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr class="line-content">
                  <td><input id="indeterminate-checkbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>CP</td>
                  <td>DD-MM-YYYY</td>
                  <td>JOE</td>
                  <td>Narration</td>
                  <td>Debit</td>
                  <td>Credit</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="line-content">
                  <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="indeterminate-checkbox" />
                  </td>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>BP</td>
                  <td>DD-MM-YYYY</td>
                  <td>PLUMZ</td>
                  <td>Narration</td>
                  <td>Debit</td>
                  <td>Credit</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="line-content">
                  <td><input id="indeterminate-checkbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
                  <td>3</td>
                  <td>CR</td>
                  <td>DD-MM-YYYY</td>
                  <td>text</td>
                  <td>Narration</td>
                  <td>Debit</td>
                  <td>Credit</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="line-content">
                  <td><input id="indeterminate-checkbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
                  <td>4</td>
                  <td>CR</td>
                  <td>DD-MM-YYYY</td>
                  <td>text</td>
                  <td>Narration</td>
                  <td>Debit</td>
                  <td>Credit</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="line-content">
                  <td><input type="checkbox" id="indeterminate-checkbox" /></td>
                  <td>5</td>
                  <td>CR</td>
                  <td>DD-MM-YYYY</td>
                  <td>text</td>
                  <td>Narration</td>
                  <td>Debit</td>
                  <td>Credit</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- Carousel controls -->
    <ul id="pagin"></ul>
    <a class="left carousel-control-prev" href="#" role="button" data-slide="prev" onload="carouselPage()">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <!-- <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> -->
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control-next" href="#" role="button" data-slide="next" onload="carouselPage()">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <!-- <span class="sr-only">Next</span> -->
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: **[tried code fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/nszokg50/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my another answer as you need with fully customize by jQuery and you can define per page records show in ***data-showperpage="4"***.
I hope this below snippet help you lot.

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
  var counting = 0;
  var slideCounter = 0;
  var slidePerpage = Number($("#records").attr("data-showperpage"));
  var countSlides = $('#records tbody tr').length;
  var totalSlideCount = Math.ceil(countSlides/slidePerpage);
  if (countSlides>1) {
    $('.carousel-control-prev').hide();
    for (var i = 1; slidePerpage>=i; i++) {
    $('#records tbody tr:nth-child('+i+')').addClass('active');
   }
  }
  else if (countSlides==1) {
    $('.carousel-control-prev,.carousel-control-next').hide();
  }
  

  //Prev Functionality
  $('.carousel-control-prev').on('click', function(){
   slideCounter = slideCounter-slidePerpage; 
   $('#records tbody tr').removeClass('active');
   for(i = slideCounter+1; (slideCounter+slidePerpage)>=i; i++){
    //console.log(i); // (4,5,6) // (7,8,9) //....
    $('#records tbody tr:nth-child('+i+')').addClass('active');
   }
   counting = counting-1;
   if (counting==0) {
      $('.carousel-control-prev').hide();
    }
    else{
      $('.carousel-control-prev,.carousel-control-next').show();
    }
  });


  //Next Functionality
  $('.carousel-control-next').on('click', function(){
   slideCounter = slideCounter+slidePerpage;  //3,6,9,12....
   $('#records tbody tr').removeClass('active');
   for(i = slideCounter+1; (slideCounter+slidePerpage)>=i; i++){
    // console.log(i); // (4,5,6) // (7,8,9) //....
    $('#records tbody tr:nth-child('+i+')').addClass('active');
   }
   counting = counting+1;
   if (totalSlideCount==counting+1) {
      $('.carousel-control-next').hide();
    }
    else{
      $('.carousel-control-prev,.carousel-control-next').show();
    }
  });
  
});
```

```css
.carousel-control-prev,.carousel-control-next{
  width: 40px!important;
  height: 40px!important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #888;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.95);
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.carousel-control-prev-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23680f79' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important;
}
.carousel-control-next-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23680f79' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 4-4-4-4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important;
}
.table-pagination tbody tr{
 display: none;
}
.table-pagination tbody tr.active{
 display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<div class="container p-3 my-1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 position-relative">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-pagination" id="records" data-showperpage="4">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>S.No</th>
              <th>Table #1</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><input id="indeterminate-checkbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>CP</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="indeterminate-checkbox" />
              </td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>BP</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input id="indeterminate-checkbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>CR</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input id="indeterminate-checkbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>CR</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="indeterminate-checkbox" /></td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>CR</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input id="indeterminate-checkbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
              <td>6</td>
              <td>CP</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="indeterminate-checkbox" />
              </td>
              <td>7</td>
              <td>BP</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input id="indeterminate-checkbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
              <td>8</td>
              <td>CR</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input id="indeterminate-checkbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
              <td>9</td>
              <td>CR</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="indeterminate-checkbox" /></td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>CR</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input id="indeterminate-checkbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
              <td>11</td>
              <td>CP</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="indeterminate-checkbox" />
              </td>
              <td>12</td>
              <td>BP</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input id="indeterminate-checkbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
              <td>13</td>
              <td>CR</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input id="indeterminate-checkbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
              <td>14</td>
              <td>CR</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="indeterminate-checkbox" /></td>
              <td>15</td>
              <td>CR</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="indeterminate-checkbox" /></td>
              <td>16</td>
              <td>CR</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="indeterminate-checkbox" /></td>
              <td>17</td>
              <td>CR</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="indeterminate-checkbox" /></td>
              <td>18</td>
              <td>CR</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="indeterminate-checkbox" /></td>
              <td>19</td>
              <td>CR</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="left carousel-control-prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="right carousel-control-next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in js code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myCarousel").carousel({
    interval: false
  });
});

    $('.carousel-control-prev-icon').hide();
    $('.carousel-control-next-icon').hide();
```

your working link https://jsfiddle.net/ao9vmc7b/

Comment: where can i add this js?

Comment: Next to $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myCarousel").carousel({
    interval: false
  });
}); code

Comment: bro! i need carousel icons i want hide prev button initially, then click next show prev icons.. prev icon only hide for initial page, then hide next icon only last page

Answer (score 0):

blyat just add this in js code and it will work

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myCarousel").carousel({
    interval: false
  nav:false,
  dots:false,

  });
});
```

Comment: still the problem ic came sir.

Answer (score 0):

just hide the particular element. Initially hide the prev button using display none property, then on clicking next button change the display property of the prev button to block and hide the next button.

```
$('.carousel-control-prev').click(function(e) {

  var nxt = document.getElementsByClassName("carousel-control-next")[0];
  nxt.style.display="block";  

  var currentPage = parseInt($("#pagin li a.current").text());
  var prevPage = currentPage - 1;      
  if (prevPage < pageSize) {
    showPage(prevPage);
    var currentObj = $("#pagin li a.current");
    $("#pagin li a.current").parent().prev().find('a').addClass('current');
    currentObj[0].className = "";   
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();}


  var prv = document.getElementsByClassName("carousel-control-prev")[0];
  prv.style.display="none";


});
$('.carousel-control-next').click(function(e) {

  var prv = document.getElementsByClassName("carousel-control-prev")[0];
  prv.style.display="block";


  var currentPage = parseInt($("#pagin li a.current").text());
  var nextPage = currentPage + 1;
  if (nextPage < pageSize) {
    showPage(nextPage);
    $("#pagin li a.current").parent().next().find('a').addClass('current');
    var currentObj = $("#pagin li a.current");
    currentObj[0].className = "";
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
  }


  var nxt = document.getElementsByClassName("carousel-control-next")[0];
  nxt.style.display="none";
});
```

check out my answer:  [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ya2tz73e/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myCarousel").carousel({
    interval: false
  });
});

pageSize = 3
incremSlide = 4
startPage = 0;
numberPage = 0;

var pageCount = $(".line-content").length / pageSize;
var totalSlidepPage = Math.floor(pageCount / incremSlide);

for (var i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
  $("#pagin").append('<li><a href="#">' + (i + 1) + '</a></li> ');
  if (i > pageSize) {
    $("#pagin li").eq(i).hide();
  }
}

var prev = $("<li/>").addClass("<").html(">").click(function() {
  startPage -= 3
  incremSlide -= 3
  slide();
});

prev.hide();

var next = $("<li/>").addClass("<").html(">").click(function() {
  startPage += 3;
  incremSlide += 3;
  slide();
});

$("#pagin").prepend(prev).append(next);

$("#pagin li").first().find("a").addClass("current");

slide = function(sens) {
  $("#pagin li").hide();

  for (t = startPage; t < incremSlide; t++) {
    $("#pagin li").eq(t + 1).show();
  }
  if (startPage == 0) {
    next.show();
    prev.hide();
  } else if (numberPage == totalSlidepPage) {
    next.hide();
    prev.show();
  } else {
    next.show();
    prev.show();
  }
}

showPage = function(page) {
  $(".line-content").hide();
  $(".line-content").each(function(n) {
    if (n >= pageSize * (page - 1) && n < pageSize * page)
      $(this).show();
  });
}

showPage(1);
$("#pagin li a").eq(0).addClass("current");

$("#pagin li a").click(function() {
  $("#pagin li a").removeClass("current");
  $(this).addClass("current");
  showPage(parseInt($(this).text()));
});
$('.carousel-control-prev').click(function(e) {

  var nxt = document.getElementsByClassName("carousel-control-next")[0];
  nxt.style.display="block";
  var currentPage = parseInt($("#pagin li a.current").text());
  var prevPage = currentPage - 1;
  
  if (prevPage < pageSize) {
    showPage(prevPage);
    var currentObj = $("#pagin li a.current");
    $("#pagin li a.current").parent().prev().find('a').addClass('current');
    currentObj[0].className = "";

  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  
  var prv = document.getElementsByClassName("carousel-control-prev")[0];
  prv.style.display="none";
});
$('.carousel-control-next').click(function(e) {
  var prv = document.getElementsByClassName("carousel-control-prev")[0];
  prv.style.display="block";
  var currentPage = parseInt($("#pagin li a.current").text());
  var nextPage = currentPage + 1;
  if (nextPage < pageSize) {
    showPage(nextPage);
    $("#pagin li a.current").parent().next().find('a').addClass('current');
    var currentObj = $("#pagin li a.current");
    currentObj[0].className = "";
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  
  var nxt = document.getElementsByClassName("carousel-control-next")[0];
  nxt.style.display="none";
});

// tried another way

function carouselPage() {
  var checkitem = function() {
    var $this;
    $this = $("#myCarousel");
    if ($("#myCarousel .carousel-inner .item:first").hasClass("active")) {
      $this.children(".left").hide();
      $this.children(".right").show();
    } else if ($("#myCarousel .carousel-inner .item:last").hasClass("active")) {
      $this.children(".right").hide();
      $this.children(".left").show();
    } else {
      $this.children(".carousel-control").show();
    }
  };

  checkitem();

  $("#myCarousel").on("slid.bs.carousel", "", checkitem);
};
```

```css
    #preModal .viewing {
      -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
      -o-transform: translate(0, -50%);
      transform: translate(0, -50%);
      top: 50%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    input[type=checkbox] {
      /* left: 23px; */
      width: 15px;
    }

    .carousel-control-prev {
      height: fit-content;
      width: fit-content;
      top: 40%;
      left: 10px;
    }

    .carousel-control-next {
      right: 10px;
      height: fit-content;
      width: fit-content;
      top: 40%;
    }

    .contd {
      /* width: 160%;
            right: 30%; */
      width: 132%;
      right: 16%;
    }

    .predefineModal {
      padding-bottom: 0px;
      padding-top: 0px;
    }

    .current,
    .carousel_li,
    .carousel_a {
      display: none;
    }

    /* .contd:hover .carousel-control-next-icon {
        display: block;
    }
    
    .contd:hover .carousel-control-prev-icon {
        display: block;
    } */

    .second {
      position: relative;
      right: 6%;
    }

    .modal-footer {
      max-width: 86%;
    }

    .indexBtn {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #680f79;
      border-color: #680f79;
      box-shadow: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-weight: 400;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      padding: 3px .75rem;
      font-size: 1rem;
      border-radius: .25rem;
    }

    .indexBtn:hover {
      background-color: #c178cf;
    }

    .diss {
      color: #5f5e5e;
      background-color: #cecece;
      border-color: #cecece;
    }

    .btn {
      padding: 3px .75rem !important;
    }

    .periodTime {
      padding: 15px;
      padding-bottom: 0px;
    }

    .carousel {
      /* background: #2f4357; */
      margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .carousel-control-prev-icon {
      background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23680f79' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important;
      position: relative;
      right: 37px;
    }

    .carousel-control-next-icon {
      background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23680f79' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 4-4-4-4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important;
      position: relative;
      left: 37px;
    }

    ul#pagin {
      display: none;
    }

    /* .carousel-control-next,
    .carousel-control-prev {
        filter: invert(100%);
    } */
    /* .carousel-control-prev-icon,
    .carousel-control-next-icon {
        position: relative;
        right: 2%;
        height: fit-content;
        width: fit-content;
        outline: black;
        background-size: 100%, 100%;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 1px solid black;
        background-image: none;
    }
    
    .carousel-control-next-icon:after {
        content: '>';
        font-size: 35px;
        color: #680f79;
        font-weight: 800;
    }
    
    .carousel-control-prev-icon:after {
        content: '<';
        font-size: 35px;
        color: #680f79;
        font-weight: 800;
    } */

    .carousel-item {
      min-height: 180px;
      filter: blur(.0px) !important;
      /* transform: translateZ(0) !important; */
      backface-visibility: hidden !important;
      /* Prevent carousel from being distorted if for some reason image doesn't load */
    }

    .bs-example {
      margin: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      margin-top: 0px;
    }

    .carousel-indicators li {
      background-color: #9C27B0 !important;
    }

    .ui-widget.ui-widget-content {
      right: 0px !important;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 17px;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>



<div class="modal-body predefineModal">
  <div class="bs-example">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
      <!-- Wrapper for carousel items -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
              <thead class="party_head">
                <tr>
                  <th>#</th>
                  <th>S.No</th>
                  <th>Trans.Type</th>
                  <th>Voucher Date</th>
                  <th>To A/c Name</th>
                  <th>Narration</th>
                  <th>Debit</th>
                  <th>Credit</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr class="line-content">
                  <td><input id="indeterminate-checkbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>CP</td>
                  <td>DD-MM-YYYY</td>
                  <td>JOE</td>
                  <td>Narration</td>
                  <td>Debit</td>
                  <td>Credit</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="line-content">
                  <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="indeterminate-checkbox" />
                  </td>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>BP</td>
                  <td>DD-MM-YYYY</td>
                  <td>PLUMZ</td>
                  <td>Narration</td>
                  <td>Debit</td>
                  <td>Credit</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="line-content">
                  <td><input id="indeterminate-checkbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
                  <td>3</td>
                  <td>CR</td>
                  <td>DD-MM-YYYY</td>
                  <td>text</td>
                  <td>Narration</td>
                  <td>Debit</td>
                  <td>Credit</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="line-content">
                  <td><input id="indeterminate-checkbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
                  <td>4</td>
                  <td>CR</td>
                  <td>DD-MM-YYYY</td>
                  <td>text</td>
                  <td>Narration</td>
                  <td>Debit</td>
                  <td>Credit</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="line-content">
                  <td><input type="checkbox" id="indeterminate-checkbox" /></td>
                  <td>5</td>
                  <td>CR</td>
                  <td>DD-MM-YYYY</td>
                  <td>text</td>
                  <td>Narration</td>
                  <td>Debit</td>
                  <td>Credit</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- Carousel controls -->
    <ul id="pagin"></ul>
    <a class="left carousel-control-prev" style="display:none;" href="#" role="button" data-slide="prev" onload="carouselPage()">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <!-- <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> -->
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control-next" href="#" role="button" data-slide="next" onload="carouselPage()">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <!-- <span class="sr-only">Next</span> -->
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if i have 3 pages in carousel table, that time the next icon going to hide why?

Answer (score 0):

From bootstrap carousel we can count **total slides** and then check with **direction** from ***left*** to ***right*** after slide event fire and add this  ***data-interval="false"*** data attribute also. 
1st count slides when page is ready. If greater than ***1*** then **prev button hide** or **equal to 1** then **prev and next both** will hide.

I hope this below snippet will help you.

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
  var countSlides = $('#myCarousel .carousel-item').length;
  if (countSlides>1) {
    $('#myCarousel .carousel-control-prev').hide();
  }
  else if (countSlides==1) {
    $('#myCarousel .carousel-control-prev, #myCarousel .carousel-control-next').hide();
  }
  // Checking on next & prev
  var countSlide = 1;  
  $(document).on('slide.bs.carousel', '#myCarousel', function(e) {
    var totalSlide = $('#'+e.target.id + ' .carousel-item').length;
    if (e.direction=='left') {
      countSlide = countSlide+1;
      if (totalSlide==countSlide) {
        $('#'+e.target.id + ' .carousel-control-next').hide();
      }
      else{
        $('#'+e.target.id + ' .carousel-control-prev').show();
        $('#'+e.target.id + ' .carousel-control-next').show();
      }
    }
    else if(e.direction=='right') {
      countSlide = countSlide-1;
      if (countSlide==1) {
        $('#'+e.target.id + ' .carousel-control-prev').hide();
      }
      else{
        $('#'+e.target.id + ' .carousel-control-prev').show();
        $('#'+e.target.id + ' .carousel-control-next').show();
      }
    } 
  });
});
```

```css
.carousel-control-prev,.carousel-control-next{
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #888;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.95);
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-control-prev-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23680f79' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important;
}
.carousel-control-next-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23680f79' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 4-4-4-4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<div class="container py-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
        <!-- Wrapper for carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead class="party_head">
                  <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>S.No</th>
                    <th>Table #1</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr class="line-content">
                    <td><input id="indeterminate-checkbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>CP</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="line-content">
                    <td>
                      <input type="checkbox" id="indeterminate-checkbox" />
                    </td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>BP</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="line-content">
                    <td><input id="indeterminate-checkbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>CR</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="line-content">
                    <td><input id="indeterminate-checkbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>CR</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="line-content">
                    <td><input type="checkbox" id="indeterminate-checkbox" /></td>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>CR</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead class="party_head">
                  <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>S.No</th>
                    <th>Table #2</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr class="line-content">
                    <td><input id="indeterminate-checkbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>CP</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="line-content">
                    <td>
                      <input type="checkbox" id="indeterminate-checkbox" />
                    </td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>BP</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="line-content">
                    <td><input id="indeterminate-checkbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>CR</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="line-content">
                    <td><input id="indeterminate-checkbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>CR</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="line-content">
                    <td><input type="checkbox" id="indeterminate-checkbox" /></td>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>CR</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead class="party_head">
                  <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>S.No</th>
                    <th>Table #3</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr class="line-content">
                    <td><input id="indeterminate-checkbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>CP</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="line-content">
                    <td>
                      <input type="checkbox" id="indeterminate-checkbox" />
                    </td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>BP</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="line-content">
                    <td><input id="indeterminate-checkbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>CR</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="line-content">
                    <td><input id="indeterminate-checkbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>CR</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="line-content">
                    <td><input type="checkbox" id="indeterminate-checkbox" /></td>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>CR</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead class="party_head">
                  <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>S.No</th>
                    <th>Table #4</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr class="line-content">
                    <td><input id="indeterminate-checkbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>CP</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="line-content">
                    <td>
                      <input type="checkbox" id="indeterminate-checkbox" />
                    </td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>BP</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="line-content">
                    <td><input id="indeterminate-checkbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>CR</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="line-content">
                    <td><input id="indeterminate-checkbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>CR</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="line-content">
                    <td><input type="checkbox" id="indeterminate-checkbox" /></td>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>CR</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Carousel controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, and I have only one table. i want to paginations in carousel icons like next/prev, for example i have 10 rows and my paginate condition is show only 3 rows remaing all are under the pagination. that only my problem now..

Comment: `@Joe` If you want pagination functionality so you can use like this https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4.html

Comment: `@Joe` If you don't want to use **datatable** library so you can check my **another answer** which that working as click next/prev buttons. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59588070/how-to-disable-or-hide-carousel-next-prev-icons-using-jquery/59591151#59591151